# Use of Matplotlib without pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to clean up the library we have at the section to create plots (python3+matplotlib) and one of the nightmares is the pyplot usage.

The idea is to have the figure creation and the rendering split and avoid using the pyplot. In theory the steps are easy:

- Create the figure with matplotlib.figure.Figure
- Choose a backend
- Associate it to a canvas and if the backend has GUI to a manager
- Show or save to file

So I finished with the following demo code that *works*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import importlib

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def fancy_plot():
    """
    Create a graph to render it in any canvas

    Returns:
        A Matplotlib Figure
    """
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [-1, 1, 0, 2])
    ax.set_title('Important graph')
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')

    return fig


def select_backend(name=None):
    """
    Extracted from matplotlib.backends.__init__.py:pylab_setup

    Args:
        name: Name of the backend or None for the default one

    Returns:
        The backend module
    """
    # Import the requested backend into a generic module object
    if name is None:
        # validates, to match all_backends
        name = matplotlib.get_backend()
    if name.startswith('module://'):
        backend_name = name[9:]
    else:
        backend_name = 'backend_' + name
        backend_name = backend_name.lower()  # until we banish mixed case
        backend_name = 'matplotlib.backends.%s' % backend_name.lower()

    return importlib.import_module(backend_name)


def is_gui_backend(backend):
    """
    Check if the backend has a GUI or not.

    Args:
        backend: Module from matplotlib.backends.*

    Returns:
        True if the backend is in the list of matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk
    """
    name = backend.__name__.lower()
    if '_' not in name:
        return False
    # Deal with the pesky capitalisation...
    interactive = [txt.lower() for txt in matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk]

    return name.split('_')[-1] in interactive


def main():

    # Create a plot, not linked to any backend
    fig = fancy_plot()

    # Select the backend from command line
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        name = None
    else:
        name = sys.argv[1]

    # Now connect to the backend to effectively plot it
    backend = select_backend(name)

    if is_gui_backend(backend):
        print('Create Manager')
        # Use the machinery to create a canvas and a window to show it
        manager = backend.new_figure_manager_given_figure(1, fig)
        manager.show()
        backend.Show().mainloop()
    else:
        # Only the canvas is needed
        print('Just save to file')
        canvas = backend.FigureCanvas(fig)
        # This can be canvas.print_figure but savefig does a few more...
        fig.savefig('fancy')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But there are many ugly aspects.

To detect if the backend is a gui I cut the module name and search for it in the rcsetup list. There is any better way to check this? I am thinking on something like hasattr(backend, 'gui')

When the backend is a gui to enter in the main loop if I just do `backend.show()` it exits immediately.
The problem is that in matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend.show there is the code:

```
managers = Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()
if not managers:
    return
```

That makes show only for pyplot figures... Ok, so I need to access the _Backend.mainloop field.
The problem is that the only way I have found to access is using the
`backend.Show().mainloop()` that seems like a back-compatibility piece of code that might vanish in any moment.

So to summarise my questions are:

1. Is this approach right?

   EDIT: Right I mean to try to use matplotlib without using pyplot...
   in the line of https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/agg_oo_sgskip.html
2. There is a nicer way to see if the backend is gui-related?
3. There is a better way to access to the GUI main loop?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason to avoid pyplot if at the end you are trying to emulate everything that pyplot makes so easy for you?

Comment: You are right in that pyplot makes creating a figure easy and that's why I want to use the FigureManager. The problem arises when the code must be in a library shared by many people that uses matplotlib in different ways. We have break the things many times because some code is using matplotlib.use while other use MPLBACKEND or ~.config/matplotlib...

Comment: So the usual way is to let the user decide on his backend. If that is not wanted, you may embed the figure in your GUI and force the user to use it. I can't imagine that anything in between is useful.

Comment: The objective is let the user decide the backend. The fancy_figure function is part of a library that is used by many programs or the command line. But the library needs to provide also rendering capacity to either show the figures in screen or store to a file with a common set of properties/actions. So the idea is that the code in main is also part of the library... in between the user has setup the backend and tuned the figures.

Comment: If the user is to decide on his backend, pyplot seems the way to go. So I probably did not understand the reason not to use it at all.

Comment: Is the approach I followed until now, everyone uses pyplot and almost work. The problem arises when some of the common code has to work from a code inserted in a Gtk application but also used to create a SVG... then the order of importing code is important: who's the first to import pyplot. And also in this way from a library point of view the logic is better controlled, without things happening magically in the pyplot state machine.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention is that my objective is to work in the same line as https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/agg_oo_sgskip.html but without hardcoding the backend